# VSCode debug external npm libraries

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-code

Let's say I'm using `jscodeshift` and have the following npm script:

```
 "start": "jscodeshift -t transform.js ./index.js
```

So `jscodeshift` will run the `transform.js` file, and do its thing. There is a way to use VSCode debugger tools to add a breakpoint to this file?